# check if a string has only white characters in python

Tags: python, string

What is the easyest way to check if a String has only white characters, like \r \t \n " "?

Comment: I would use a regular expression ('re') to search for the characters/values you want.

Comment: @AlbertoPonte using a Regex on such a task should be considered criminal

Comment: @WaleedKhan `not foo.strip()` is what you are looking for (`str.trim()` doesn't exist in Python, and comparing to an empty string is best replaced with `not`), although it's still not the best option here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `isspace()` method on strings tells you this:

```
>>> "   ".isspace()
True
>>> " x  ".isspace()
False
```

Another option is to strip the ends:

```
if not s.strip():
    print "It was all whitespace!"
```

Answer (score -1):

## The Desired Behavior

The following contains a description of the desired behavior....

---

#### Specific Behavior

| INPUT | DESCRIPTION | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `"a b c"` | Letters and Spaces mixed together. | False |
| `"abc"` | Letters Only | False |
| `" "` | Three Spaces | True |
| `""` | Empty String | No Exception is raised. It undefined whether the return value is True or False |
| `" "` | One Space | True |
| `"\t"` | Tab-character | True |
| `"\r"` | Carriage Return | True |
| `"\n"` | Line-Feed | True |
| `"\v"` | Vertical Tab | True |
| `"\f"` | form-feed | True |
| `"\t\v\t\rn"` | Mixture of tabs and other white characters | True |

---

#### General Behavior

In ASCII, the whitespace characters are:

> - space ( ' ' )
> - tab ( '\t' )
> - carriage return ( '\r' )
> - newline ( '\n' )
> - vertical tab ( '\v' )
> - formfeed ( '\f' )

```python
def is_pure_white(itext:str) -> bool:
    """
        DOCUMENTATION

        Returns true if all characters in the string are 
        spaces, or line-feeds, or tabs, or other things that look
        white when the text is printed onto a white sheet of paper.  
        
        The input parameter `itext` is any string of text. 
 
        The output is a Boolean (True or False)        
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

---

#### Behavior for the Empty String

Note that the empty string `""` is a strange ***[corner case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case)***.

Consider...

| CASE NUMBER | MATHEMATICIANS SYMBOL | DESCIPTION | BEHAVIOR FOR EMPTY STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 of 2 | ∃ | There exists at least one character in the string which is not a white-space character | `False` for the empty string |
| 2 of 2 | ∀ | Either the string is empty, or there is at least one character in the string, and that character is white-space, and all other characters in the string are also white-space. | `True` for the empty string |

---

## Implementation One
Using a For Loop

#### Implementation 1.1
One Return Statement Only

```python
def is_pure_white(itext:str)  -> bool:
    r = True
    for ch in itext:
        if ch not in [' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\v', '\f']: 
            r = False
            break 
    return r
```

---

#### Implementation 1.2
Two Return Statements

```python
def is_pure_white(itext:str)  -> bool:
    for ch in itext:
        if ch not in [' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\v', '\f']: 
            return False
    return True
```

---

## Implementation Two
Remove Leading and Trailing White-Space

```python
def is_pure_white(itext:str)  -> bool:
    """
        [
            INSTRUCTIONS 
            ON *HOW TO USE* THIS FUNCTION GO HERE

            NOTES ABOUT *HOW IT WORKS* ARE FORBIDDEN HERE
            DO NOT WRITE ABOUT THE INNER WORKINGS OR IMPLEMENTATION
        ]
    """
    # BEGIN DOCUMENTATION FOR IMPLEMENTATION (HOW IT WORKS)  
    #
    #     FIRST....
    #         Remove Leading and Trailing White-Space
    #
    #     SECONDLY....
    #         Check IF the Length of the string is zero.   
    # 
    # END DOCUMENTATION FOR IMPLEMENTATION (HOW IT WORKS)  
 
    text = itext.strip()
        if len(text) > 1:
            return False
        # else:
        #     empty string or all white space characters 
    return True
```

---

## Option Three
Using the Regular Expression Engine

```python
import re # regular expression library 

def is_pure_white(itext:str) -> bool:
    pattern = "\s"
    spaces = re.findall(pattern, itext)
    status = len(spaces) == len(itext)
    return status
```

---

## Option Four
Predicate Dispatching

This one requires a special library that most people don't have.

```python
import casedispatching as kispatch 

@kispatch(lambda stryng: min(2, len(stryng)) ) 
def is_pure_white(itext:str) -> bool:
    praise NotImplementedError()  

###############################################################

@is_pure_white.register(0) 
def _(itext:str) -> bool:
    """ empty string """ 
    return True 

###############################################################

@is_pure_white.register(1) 
def _(ch:str) -> bool:
    status = ch in [' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\v', '\f']   
    return status   

################################################################

@is_pure_white.register(2) 
def _(itext:str) -> bool:
    # recursive implementation 
    for ch in itext:
        if not is_pure_white(ch) 
            return False
    return True
```

---

## A Simple Driver used for Testing Purposes

You can test your code, my code, or someone else's code using the following driver:

```python
txt2 = "\t\t \n"
txt1 = "The rain in Spain\n\r"

cases = [txt1, txt2]

for case in cases:
    result = is_pure_white(case)
    print(repr(case).ljust(40), result)
```